# JSON Schema for java class

Tags: javascript, json, jaxb, jax-rs, jsonschema

I am using Jackson 1.5 to generate JSON schema and trying to generate json schema for java class

I tried the below code for Employee class

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {
int id;
String name;
Date date;
}
```

---

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonSchema jsonSchema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(Employee.class);
```

---

The above code generated number type for date field, do i need to specify any annotation to convert date type?

```
{
 "type": "object",
 "optional": true,
 "items":    {
 "type": "number",
 "optional": true
},
 "properties":{
   "id":       {
     "type": "integer",
     "optional": true
  },
  "name":       {
     "type": "string",
     "optional": true
  },
  "date":       {
     "type": "number",
     "optional": true
  }
}
}
```

Also, if the field (e.g., id) is required, how do i specify to show as "required":true in the JSON schema?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Jackson does not support validation, to validate **required** fields, for example. [Beans Validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) could be done for this, instead.

And for the date conversion issue, the [Jackson FAQ](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling) does a great job showing all the ways to handle this.

Comment: I don't need to validate field. I just need to specify it as "meta" as "required" : true for the users when they request to check which fields are required in the class.

Answer (score 0):

"Required" can be specified with the "@JsonProperty(required = true)" annotation.

```
public class Employee {
    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    int id;

    String name;

    Date date;
}
```

There is no primitive "date" type in the JSON schema standard, nor is there inherent support for any date validation annotation in Jackson.

However, there is a JSON schema concept called "format", which clarifies a "string" type. One of the basic supported formats here is "date-time", which is meant to use dates of the format given by [RFC 3339, section 5.6.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339). It is possible to have the mapper support this format, but it's not possible, without significant extension, to add the "format" annotation to the JSON schema.

Comment: Note that `required` attribute does nothing during deserialization, see javadocs http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#required%28%29

Comment: This is true, but it does produce the right field in the JSON schema definition, which is still helpful with other tools.